# Jenkins: Is there any way to cleanup Jenkins workspace?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, accurev

How can I cleanup the workspace in Jenkins? I am using `AccuRev` as version control tool.

I created `freestyle` projects in Jenkins.

Answer (score 130):

There is a way to cleanup workspace in Jenkins. You can clean up the workspace before build or after build.

First, install [Workspace Cleanup Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Workspace+Cleanup+Plugin).

To clean up the workspace before build:
Under **Build Environment,** check the box that says **Delete workspace before build starts.**

To clean up the workspace after the build:
Under the heading **Post-build Actions** select **Delete workspace when build is done** from the **Add Post-build Actions** drop down menu.

Comment: Thanks a lot Nagendra. I am able to fix this issue using workspace cleanup  plugin.

Comment: what will happen if i dont clean the workspace ? is it fetching the changes from the remote url or just building over same thing again and again?

Comment: @alphaguy Jenkins creates a new workspace for each build that you run, so if you don't delete the workspaces then eventually your node will run out of space.

Comment: Can we reuse the workspace.. currently when i push the code it clone from git server then start the build. This takes a long process  adding extra to build process! can we just pick the latest commit ? @MilesWinther

Comment: @alphaguy You can use a reference repo, see the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9932036/6221831

Answer (score 67):

If you want to manually clean it up, for me with my version of jenkins (didn't appear to need an extra plugin installed, but who knows), there is a "workspace" link on the left column, click on your project, then on "workspace", then a "Wipe out current workspace" link appears beneath it on the left hand side column.
[image: screenshot]

Comment: I don’t see that, unfortunately. Sure it is not a plugin?

Comment: Hmm it seems that the "Workspace Cleanup Plugin" is indeed one of the plugins that is installed "by default."  However, after removing it, I still have that link and it seems to still function.  So...not sure where it comes from. V2.121.3

Comment: This worked but I had to click on the workspace link twice: the first one to go to the "workspace" page, the second time to actually show the "Wipe out current workspace" link. I guess it's an info you can include in the answer.

Comment: What Jenkins version is this one? Because mine does not show this option (probably mine is too old).

Comment: V2.121.3  not sure on other versions

Comment: You can achieve the same result if you temporarily configure "Wipe out repository & force clone" in the Additional Behaviours section of your Job configuration.

Comment: 2.319.1, this does not exist on a clean install. I would not trust "I removed the plugin and its still there". Also Workspace Cleanup Plugin is installed on my instance, this link does not exist in a single pipeline or multi-branch pipeline.

Answer (score 48):

[Workspace Cleanup Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/ws-cleanup/)

In Jenkins file add

```
cleanWs()
```

This will delete the workspace after the build is complete

Comment: I really appreciate this answer because I had the plugin installed from the other answers but this is what got it to work for my setup. Adding to that, I followed the links to the same plugin in the other answers, but `cleanWs()` wasn't present on the plugin landing page as syntax to add to my `Jenkinsfile`.

Answer (score 41):

Beside above solutions, there is a more "COMMON" way - directly delete the largest space consumer from Linux machine. You can follow the below steps:

1. Login to Jenkins machine (Putty)
   [image]
2. cd to the Jenkins installation path

> Using ls -lart to list out hidden folder also, normally jenkin
>   installation is placed in .jenkins/ folder
>
> ```
> [xxxxx ~]$ ls -lart
>
> drwxrwxr-x 12 xxxx  4096 Feb  8 02:08 .jenkins/
> ```

3. list out the folders spaces

> `Use df -h` to show Disk space in high level
>
> `du -sh ./*/` to list out total memory for each subfolder in current
>   path.
>
> `du -a /etc/ | sort -n -r | head -n 10` will list top 10 directories
>   eating disk space in /etc/

4. Delete old build or other large size folder

> Normally ./job/ folder or ./workspace/ folder can be the largest
>   folder. Please go inside and delete base on you need (DO NOT delete entire folder).
>
> `rm -rf theFolderToDelete`

[image]

Comment: Not sure why voted down. This sounds like a good option for Jenkins admins. Agree not for "read-only" users.

Comment: 1. This doesn't really answer the question asked and 2. my Jenkins server is running on Windows.

Comment: @mjaggard The question was asked by some one else and he did not mention if it is for Windows only. Also he asked how to cleanup workspace (not limited to frontend/client). Am I missing anything obvious here?

Comment: I totally agree with @takias, it seems a valid answer for the question. And a good one if you have enough permission to do it.

Comment: This is an answer to "how do I recover space on a GNU/Linux machine" not jenkins specific.

Comment: I imagine this is the answer that my coworker found when he ran a script to delete any nested folders in the `/jobs/` directory. Problem is, if you have subfolders of jobs in Jenkins (like I did) the script will delete the JOB configuration, and not the build files. It wiped out multiple job configurations and we had to pull from backups to recreate them. ONLY use the UI/BuildDiscarder plugins and options to clean up the Master node. NEVER manually delete anything from the jobs folder.

Answer (score 37):

**IMPORTANT:** It is safe to remove the workspace for a given Jenkins job as long as the job is not currently running!

**NOTE:** I am assuming your `$JENKINS_HOME` is set to the default: `/var/jenkins_home`.

#### Clean up one workspace

`rm -rf /var/jenkins_home/workspaces/<workspace>`

#### Clean up all workspaces

`rm -rf /var/jenkins_home/workspaces/*`

#### Clean up all workspaces with a few exceptions

This one uses grep to create a whitelist:

```
ls /var/jenkins_home/workspace \ 
  | grep -v -E '(job-to-skip|another-job-to-skip)$' \
  | xargs -I {} rm -rf /var/jenkins_home/workspace/{}
```

#### Clean up 10 largest workspaces

This one uses du and sort to list workspaces in order of largest to smallest. Then, it uses head to grab the first 10:

```
du -d 1 /var/jenkins_home/workspace \
  | sort -n -r \
  | head -n 10 \
  | xargs -I {} rm -rf /var/jenkins_home/workspace/{}
```

Comment: This is dangerous as jobs might be using those workspaces.

Comment: yikes... dont ever do this when using perforce, least not without some additional padding in your pipeline or you'll be in a world of hurt !

Comment: I used `rm -rf /var/jenkins_home/workspaces/<workspace>` after checking that no pipelines were executing (small team, I can disable build agents) to "fix" a git error causing a pipeline to fail.

Answer (score 19):

You can run the below script in the *Manage Jenkins* → *Scripts Console* for deleting the workspaces of all the jobs at one shot. We did this to clean up space on the file system.

```groovy
import hudson.model.*
// For each project
for(item in Hudson.instance.items) {
  // check that job is not building
  if(!item.isBuilding()) {
    println("Wiping out workspace of job "+item.name)
    item.doDoWipeOutWorkspace()
  }
  else {
    println("Skipping job "+item.name+", currently building")
  }
}
```

Comment: this does not work for me, it shows java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'items' on null object .

Comment: This script did nothing for me. It shows list of my projects with " Wiping out...", but doesn't clean anything. The workspace directory remains full.

Answer (score 6):

There is an option to do it. Configure -> Post-build Actions 
The option comes by default at least in Jenkins version 2.236

[image]

Answer (score 5):

If you want to just remove one dir (or file) you can use Groovy and Manage Jenkins → Scripts Console run a script which removes it.

For example, you can look at the files with:

```
dh = new File('./bitnami/jenkins/jenkins_home/workspace/jobname/folder')
dh.eachFile {
  println(it)
}
```

And then, when you have the folder you want to delete in `dh`, you could simply append the next code:

```
dh.deleteDir()
```

And it will be deleted.

Note: The path shown in the example is for a Bitnami Jenkins installation, yours could be different.

Answer (score 4):

not allowed to comment, therefore:

The answer from [Upen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1811426/upen) works just fine, but not if you have Jenkins Pipeline Jobs mixed with Freestyle Jobs. There is no such Method as DoWipeWorkspace on Pipeline Jobs. 
So I modified the Script in order to skip those:

```
import hudson.model.*
import org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowJob

// For each project
for(item in Hudson.instance.items) {
  // check that job is not building
  if(!item.isBuilding() && !(item instanceof WorkflowJob))
  {
    println("Wiping out workspace of job "+item.name)
    item.doDoWipeOutWorkspace()
  }
  else {
    println("Skipping job "+item.name+", currently building")
  }
}
```

you could also filter by Job Names if required:
`item.getDisplayName().toLowerCase().contains("release")`

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the question is about cleaning the workspace of the current job, you can run:

```
test -n "$WORKSPACE" && rm -rf "$WORKSPACE"/*
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need to install this plugin before the options mentioned above will appear

[Workspace Cleanup Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Workspace+Cleanup+Plugin)

This plugin add the check box to all job configs to allow you to delete the whole workspace before any steps (inc source control) are run

This is useful to make sure you always start from a known point to guarantee how you build will run

Comment: Please add some information that your link is containing. Link-only answer are not what we are looking for at SO! :)

Comment: This add's no more information that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28728663/542251) hasn't already covered. In fact it add's a **lot** less

Answer (score 1):

For those, who have builds within Docker under `root` user, following method may help:

```java
def cleanupWorkspaceAsRoot() {
  log.notice "Removing workspace contents: $WORKSPACE !"
  docker.image('alpine').inside('-u root --env WORKSPACE') { // use docker instead of sudo // TODO make ALL docker builds work as non-ROOT, so there is no root-owned files
    sh 'test -n "$WORKSPACE" && rm -rf "$WORKSPACE"/*'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are using Windows as your agent, you can use.

```
rmdir /s /q "folder path ending with \"
```

and if you are using linux machine as agent, you can use,

```
rm -rvf "directory"
```

But I wouldn't suggest this approach as it will create multiple chances of conflict and build failures.

Best approach is to use pipeline dependency. Create a main pipeline to delete the directory of the pipeline you want to delete and run the pipeline once delete is successful. You can use triggers to start the new build once delete is completed or vice versa to delete the directory once the build is completed.

```
pipeline {
    agent
    {
        node {
                label 'master'
                customWorkspace "${env.JobPath}"
              }
    }

    stages 
    {
        stage('Start') {
            steps {
                sh 'ls'
            }
        }

        stage ('Invoke_pipeline') {
            steps {
                build job: 'pipeline1', parameters: [
                string(name: 'param1', value: "value1")
                ]
            }
        }

        stage('End') {
            steps {
                sh 'ls'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Code Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43337070/how-to-invoke-a-jenkins-pipeline-a-in-another-jenkins-pipeline-b)

https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-build-step/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using docker, it might create files (from within docker container) that are not owned by user jenkins, and thus you need to use sudo to remove them:

```
    sh "sudo rm -rf \"$WORKSPACE\"/*"
    sh "sudo rm -rf \"$WORKSPACE\"/.*"
```

For this to work, you need to add /etc/sudoers -permission for user jenkins (please edit /etc/sudoers) e.g (these are full permissions without password):

```
jenkins ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Comment: If the `$WORKSPACE` variable gets empty for any reason, it is a recipe for a disaster: you'll get `sudo rm -rf /*` as a result. You could use it in this safer way: `"${WORKSPACE:?}"/*`. For `:?` explanation:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/8889350/10788155