# How to invoke a jenkins pipeline A in another jenkins pipeline B

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-2

I have two Jenkins pipelines, let's say pipeline-A and pipeline-B. I want to invoke pipeline-A in pipeline-B. How can I do this?

(pipeline-A is a subset of pipeline-B. Pipeline-A is responsible for doing some routine stuff which can be reused in pipeline-B)

I have installed Jenkins 2.41 on my machine.

Comment: have you tried triggering it as a normal job: 

node {
     def job = build job: 'some-pipeline'
}

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Following solution works for me:

```
pipeline {
    agent
    {
        node {
                label 'master'
                customWorkspace "${env.JobPath}"
              }
    }

    stages 
    {
        stage('Start') {
            steps {
                sh 'ls'
            }
        }

        stage ('Invoke_pipeline') {
            steps {
                build job: 'pipeline1', parameters: [
                string(name: 'param1', value: "value1")
                ]
            }
        }

        stage('End') {
            steps {
                sh 'ls'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Adding link of the official documentation of "Pipeline: Build Step" here:
https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-build-step/

Comment: How is this working for you? Is "pipeline1" actually a "pipeline{}"? I get this error: "Waiting for non-job items is not supported". I think this is just for jobs not full pipelines

Comment: pipeline1 is actually another pipeline name that you need to invoke here.

Comment: @red888 If you get the error `ERROR: Waiting for non-job items is not supported`, you may need to specify the branch: `build job: 'pipeline1/master', parameters: [`

Comment: Is there a way to know the name of parent pipeline when child pipeline is running?

Comment: You can pass the JOB_NAME environment variable as a paramter to the child job.

Comment: Do I need always a defined Jenkins-Job (as Pipeline-Job) for calling with "build job"? Or can I call the Groovy-Code with a complete pipeline direct from parent pipeline?
An example: I have a parametrized pipeline for building something. With different small other pipelines I want to start the parametrized pipeline with different parameter-combinations. Do I need a (parametrized)) jenkins-job for the build-pipeline or can I call the big pipeline direct?

Comment: I have tried with Pipeline Job only but it should work for other standard jobs als well.

Comment: This question has gained lot of traction in last years. Has anyone succeeded in getting job path or job ID of the child job from parent job or vice versa?

Comment: I’m trying to start a new job inside a jenkinsfile using `build(job:”app/other/repo/)` But It is failing due to “ Waiting for non-job items is not supported” How can start the new job from another repo from the first Jenkinsfile?

Comment: Watch out that the new build job might run on a different Git commit than the parent job if the branch has changed in the meantime.

Comment: i see your 'stringifying' the parameters. so you are not able to pass a map as a parameter?

Answer (score 76):

A little unclear if you want to invoke another pipeline script or job, so I'll answer both:

**Pipeline script**

The "load" step will execute the other pipeline script. If you have both scripts in the same directory, you can load it like this:

```
def pipelineA = load "pipeline_A.groovy"
pipelineA.someMethod()
```

Other script (`pipeline_a.groovy`):

```
def someMethod() {
    //do something
}

return this
```

**Pipeline job**

If you are talking about executing another pipeline job,
the `build job` step in your `Jenkinsfile` can accomplish this:

```
build job: '<Project name>', propagate: true, wait: true
```

`propagate`: Propagate errors

`wait`: Wait for completion

If you have parameters for the job, you can add them like this:

```
build job: '<Project name>', parameters: [[$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'param1', value: 'test_param']]
```

Comment: Just want to know how can I get the status of child pipeline in the parent pipeline. I want to proceed the parent pipeline based on the result of the child pipeline.

Comment: Is there a way to pass "current build parameters" from one job to another? as in the "old jenkins"

Comment: I used the first example from 'pipeline job', with propagate and wait, but Jenkins gives me this error: ERROR: Waiting for non-job items is not supported. Any clue what I did wrong?

Comment: I suspect you try to start a job that does not exist or you use the wrong name. If you for example want to call a multibranch job, use: `build job: "my-job/my-branch-name", propagate: true, wait: true`.

Comment: Is there a way to dynamically use the environmental BRANCH_NAME variable from the multibranch job? Something like `build job: "my-job/$BRANCH_NAME", propagate: true, wait: true`? I keep getting error with the syntax I'm using. I've tried env.BRANCH_NAME as well. The errors are "no items named my-job/$BRANCH_NAME found (I am using my actual job name in place of "my-job").

Comment: @msteppe91 the pipeline for the downstream branch needs to exist already before you can build. I'm running into the same error, can't find a workaround. The environment variable should be used like this, though: `${BRANCH_NAME}`

Comment: @colti The downstream branch already existed. What I needed to do was specify BRANCH_NAME as `${env.BRANCH_NAME}`. So my final call turned out to be something like:
`build job: "Downstream_Job/${env.BRANCH_NAME}", parameters: [string(name: 'some_param', value: 'true')]`

Comment: How could one show the stages in the sub-pipeline show up in the BlueOcean UI?

Comment: if i call the other script, it uses a different workspace. is there a way to prevent this, so that both scripts are using the same?

Comment: You can use the `ws(c:\workspace\path\here){ code here }` to set location of the workspace your job runs in.

Comment: “build job: "my-job/my-branch-name", propagate: true, wait: true“ is this syntax valid for another repo? 
For example, can I use this: “my-job/path/another/repo”

Comment: Hi, what if my multibranch pipeline in the folder? Is it `build job: 'name-folder/pipeline1/master'`, right?

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned by @Matias Snellingen and @Céline Aussourd, in the case of launching a multibranch job you have to specify the branch to build like this :

```
stage ('Invoke_pipeline') {
    steps {
        build job: 'pipeline1/master', parameters: [
        string(name: 'param1', value: "value1")
        ]
    }
}
```

In my case it solved the problem.

Comment: Hi, how ca n I access this parameter in the other pipeline?

Comment: @awiechert Yep you can.

Comment: So, we done running the pipeline1 first on jenkins, then we can call out the name of job. Is it right?

Comment: How do you pass a boolean value this way?

Answer (score 2):

I am going to post my solution, which is similar to @Michael COLL, @Matias Snellingen, and @Céline Aussourd.
For the multibranch pipeline I am using the following code in Jenkinsfile to trigger my multibranch B with multibranch A (in the example there are two cases for pipeline and multibranch pipeline):

```
post {      
      always {
            echo 'We are in post part and Jenkins build with QA tests is going to be triggered.'
            // For triggering Pipeline
            //build job: 'WGF-QA WITH ALLURE', parameters: [string(name: 'QA-Automation', value: 'value from Build pipeline')]
            // For triggering Multibranch Pipeline
            build job: 'Testing QA/QA Selenium Tests/feature%2FGET-585', parameters: [string(name: 'QA-Automation', value: 'value from Build pipeline')]
      } 
    }
```

**Just be sure to define the whole path to the branch as is defined in the case and instead of / in branch name use %2F** (feature/GET-585 -> feature%2FGET-585).

Comment: Can you return success/fail from your build job?

Answer (score 1):

To add to what @matias-snellingen said.  If you have multiple functions, the `return this` should be under the function that will be called in the main pipeline script. For example in :

```
def someMethod() {
   helperMethod1() 
   helperMethod2()
} 
return this 

def helperMethod1(){ 
   //do stuff
} 

def helperMethod2(){
  //do stuff
}
```

The `someMethod()` is the one that will be called in the main pipeline script

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to create a package, load it and execute it from the package.

```
package name.of.package
import groovy.json.*

def myFunc(var1) {
return result
}
```

Than consume it

```
@Library('name_of_repo')
import name.of.package.* 
utils = new name_of_pipeline()
// here you can invoke
utils.myFunc(var)
```

hope it helps