# Triggering a multibranch pipeline job from an other multibranch pipeline

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, multibranch-pipeline

I have a scenario where but I have 2 projects (A and B), both are configured in Jenkins with multibranch pipeline jobs, problem is that Project B depends on Project A.

So I find that some times when I check in code in Project A, I also need to build ProjectB once A was built.  Now before I started investigating pipeline builds, I'd have a job per branch and then trigger in Jenkins the appropriate job for Project B for the appropriate branch.

What I'd like to set up in a Jenkinsfile so that when ProjectA/develop executes it then triggers the multibranch pipeline job for ProjectB and the same branch.

I have:

```
stage ('Trigger Tenant Builds') {
        build job: "ProjectB/${branch}", wait: false
    }
```

But my ProjectA pipeline fails with:

```
ERROR: No parameterized job named ProjectB/develop found
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've resolved this now.  What I am doing is defining an upstream trigger in project B's Jenkinsfile:

```
pipelineTriggers([ 
    upstream( 
       threshold: hudson.model.Result.SUCCESS, 
       upstreamProjects: "/ProjectA/" + env.BRANCH_NAME.replaceAll("/", "%2F") 
    )
])
```

Comment: How do you ensure that this triggers only the develop branch and not the feature branch?

Comment: Hi @vijayvithal
if you still need it, check my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43337070/how-to-invoke-a-jenkins-pipeline-a-in-another-jenkins-pipeline-b/71412961#71412961