# Is it possible to trigger Multibranch pipeline job from a regular Jenkins job under "Build other Projects"?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, multibranch-pipeline

I have 2 jobs. One is a regular freestyle job on Jenkins that is supposed to trigger another job which is a Multibranch pipeline job.

The issue is whenever I enter the name of the Multibranch job in the "Projects to Build column", I get an error - "x is not buildable". But the Multibranch job works perfectly well on its own and there are no problems with it.

Is "Build other projects" post build action (downstream project) not compatible with Jenkins pipelines? What am I missing here?

Comment: Facing same issue. We have multiple branches and we want to pass the branch(Sub_Job_Name) dynamically.

Comment: possible answer provided here https://stackoverflow.com/a/45066941/1034782

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a temporary solution, where it is required that I need to mention 'Multibranch_Pipeline_Job/Sub_Job_Name', where Sub_Job_Name is the name of one of the many jobs in the Multibranch job.

Although this works out well, it is not a very feasible solution. If a Multibranch job has many branches containing Jenkinsfiles, it is required that all these sub-jobs be mentioned separately in "Projects to Build" column.

If there is more viable solution where it is possible to execute the Multibranch pipeline job entirely (all the sub-jobs), please answer here. It would be much appreciated.