# How to know name of parent pipeline when child pipeline is running

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I have 2 Jenkins pipelines, lets call them Pipeline-A and Pipeline-B.
Pipeline-A is parent pipeline which invokes Pipeline-B (child) when it (Pipeline-A) is running.

How can i know the name of Pipeline-A (parent) when Pipeline-B (child) is running.
Is there any environment variable that i can invoke to know this?

This is important to know because there are many pipelines similar to Pipeline-A which invoke Pipeline-B.

One can refer my answer on how to invoke pipelines at following link:
[How to invoke a jenkins pipeline A in another jenkins pipeline B](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43337070/how-to-invoke-a-jenkins-pipeline-a-in-another-jenkins-pipeline-b)

Comment: How about passing the name as string parameter to the child?

Comment: Yes @JoergS, that can be done but it will introduce a new parameter. I want to know if there exists an environment variable which does the this job.