# Run one Jenkinsfile from another Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am on Jenkins     2.140
I am loading jobs from github repo
I want to have multiple Jenkinsfiles that will execute main test with different set of default parameters.
I have following setup:

```
root
  src/
      test.groovy
  test/
      Jenkinsfile
```

src/test.groovy file looks like this

```groovy
def runJob(par1, par2 ) {

    pipeline {
        agent any
        stages {
            stage("Print Status"){
                steps{
                    sh 'ls -All'
                    sh 'pip --version'
                    sh 'pip freeze'
                }
            }
        }
        
        post {
            failure {
                echo "Job Failed"
            }
        }
    }

}

return this
```

The test/Jenkinsfile looks like this:

```jenkins
pipeline {
    agent any

    parameters {
        string(defaultValue: "oneone", description: 'First param', name: 'param1')
        string(defaultValue: "twotwo", description: 'Second param', name: 'param2')
    }
    stages {
         stage("Run chaos job"){
            steps{
                 script{
                    mainJenkinsFile = load "src/test.groovy"
                    mainJenkinsFile.runJob(params.param1, params.param2)                   
                }
            }
        }
    }        
}
```

When i run it in Jenkins i get error

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: any for class: groovy.lang.Binding
    at groovy.lang.Binding.getVariable(Binding.java:63)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onGetProperty(SandboxInterceptor.java:242)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$6.call(Checker.java:288)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:292)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:268)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.getProperty(SandboxInvoker.java:29)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyAccessBlock.rawGet(PropertyAccessBlock.java:20)
    at Script1.runJob(Script1.groovy:4)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.call(jar:file:/persistent/plugins/pipeline-model-definition/WEB-INF/lib/pipeline-model-definition.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/ModelInterpreter.groovy:59)
    at Script1.runJob(Script1.groovy:3)
    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:13)
    at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyishBlock$ContinuationImpl.get(PropertyishBlock.java:74)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.LValueBlock$GetAdapter.receive(LValueBlock.java:30)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyishBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixName(PropertyishBlock.java:66)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor260.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ConstantBlock.eval(ConstantBlock.java:21)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:83)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:174)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:122)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:261)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$101(SandboxContinuable.java:34)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.lambda$run0$0(SandboxContinuable.java:59)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.GroovySandbox.runInSandbox(GroovySandbox.java:108)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:58)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:174)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:332)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$200(CpsThreadGroup.java:83)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:244)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:232)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:131)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:59)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Looks like I am missing a library or something.

Comment: Check out this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43337070/how-to-invoke-a-jenkins-pipeline-a-in-another-jenkins-pipeline-b. Use `Pipeline script` or `Pipeline job`. At this moment src/test.groovy has wrong syntax.

Comment: You probably want to look into [shared libraries](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/).

Answer (score -1):

We do the same thing (use one jenkins file that is trigger multiple times with different param) .

Here is an example for the DSL which uses the jenkinsfile :

```
pipelineJob('test/staging') {
    definition {
        properties {
            disableConcurrentBuilds()
        }
        parameters {
            stringParam('COMPONENT', null, 'backend/frontend')
            stringParam('SEMANTIC_VERSION', null, '1.0.36')
        }
        cps {
            script(readFileFromWorkspace('jobs/test/staging.Jenkinsfile'))
            sandbox()
        }
    }
}
```

And this is how we call it from within the pipeline:

```
build(job: "test/staging", parameters: [
[$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'COMPONENT', value: env.COMPONENT ],
[$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'SEMANTIC_VERSION', value: env.SEMANTIC_VERSION ]
        ])
```

Comment: But this is Job DSL, isn't it?

Comment: We use a Jenkisfile as the base of all of this:

`cps {
            script(readFileFromWorkspace('jobs/test/staging.Jenkinsfile'))
            sandbox()
        }`


Actually, you can skip the DSL file and just use the build() function, we use a DSL wrapper because we wanted it to be a cron in addition to a triggered job.

Comment: Where should i put the DSL thing. Why is everything so undocumented and complicated.

Comment: :( I hear you. We have a seed job which reads all files which ends with .groovy. https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/wiki/Tutorial---Using-the-Jenkins-Job-DSL . But like I said the important thing for your question is the trigger using the build() method

Comment: what does `sandbox()` stand for?

Comment: @Taz: it enables Groovy sandbox (like as you set checkbox). See https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/script-approval/#groovy-sandbox