# Jenkins execute Pipeline from another Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, cicd

Related: [How to invoke a jenkins pipeline A in another jenkins pipeline B](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43337070/how-to-invoke-a-jenkins-pipeline-a-in-another-jenkins-pipeline-b)

I want to decide the workspace and branch for the call too because otherwise there will be issues with git, since this job might be called mulitple times concurrently. I want it to clone/fetch the whole project if i change the workspace. Is this possible?

```
pipeline {
    agent {...}
    stages 
    {
        stage('Start') {
            steps {
                sh 'ls'
            }
        }
        stage ('Invoke_pipeline') {
            steps {
---------------> Decide Workspace and Branch for this pipeline call, ideally see the steps in the ui too
              
                build job: 'pipeline1', parameters: [
                string(name: 'param1', value: "value1")
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

want something like

```
           build job: 'pipeline1', workspace= /.A_Stage, branch= dev, parameters: [
           string(name: 'param1', value: "value1")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it the way you are trying. You will have to manually set the workspace in the second Pipeline. Something like below.

**Pipeline A**

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('First Stage') {
            steps {
                script {
                    echo "Pipeline A"
                    build job: 'PipelineB', parameters: [string(name: 'WORKSPACE_PATH', value: 'some/path/to/new/workspace')]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Pipeline B**

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    parameters {
        string(name: 'WORKSPACE_PATH', defaultValue: '', description: 'Path of the workspace from Pipeline A')
    }
    stages {
        stage('Second Stage') {
            steps {
                script {
                    def workspacePath = params.WORKSPACE_PATH
                    echo "Received workspace path from Pipeline A: ${workspacePath}"
                    sh 'pwd'
                    // Changing the workspace
                    ws(workspacePath) {
                      echo "In new workspace"
                      sh 'pwd'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```