# After removing some test cases, still displaying the old test cases in current execution report

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, allure

I have integrated the Allure report with jenkins.
I was executing some 300 test cases previously but currently, have removed around 100 test cases for this release. TestNG now executed 200 test cases only but the problem is that the consolidated latest allure report still shows me all 300 test cases and making it tough to filter the older and current test cases.

Is there any way through with we can use history in the way it displays only the current active test cases and their history without displaying all previous test cases.

Answer (score 2):

You need to cleanup the workspace before the build starts. You can configure Jenkins Workspace Cleanup plugin (see [Is there any way to cleanup Jenkins workspace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28683914/is-there-any-way-to-cleanup-jenkins-workspace) for more details) or execute Maven/Gradle `clean` command before tests.

Comment: Will it keep the history of test cases that are being executed in my current build?

Comment: Allure Jenkins Plugin handles history by itself

Comment: My jenkins job is a MultiJob project and I execute the mvn clean test command on the sub job but want the Allure Report to be generated for main job. Can u suggest what should be the good config in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to remove `allure-results` directory before running tests. you can do it by adding `maven-clean-plugin` to your `pom.xml` file:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <build>
    <plugins>
         . . .            

        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>clean-allure-results</id>
                    <phase>clean</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>clean</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <filesets>
                            <fileset>
                                <directory>path/to/allure-results</directory>
                            </fileset>
                        </filesets>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```