# Jenkins Pipeline having "Multiple candidate revisions" and is picking old one

Tags: git, jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins, continuous-deployment

i have a Jenkins multibranch Pipeline configured which should fetch sources from a remote GIT repository for a build. Jenkins no seems to "randomly" pick an old commit for the build an showing the message "Multiple candidate revisions" in Build log files.

My Pipeline is looking like:

```
checkout(
        [
            $class: 'GitSCM', 
            branches: [[name: "release/0.0.1"]],
            doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, 
            extensions: [
                [$class: 'MessageExclusion', excludedMessage: '(?s)^\\[DOC\\] Robot.*']
            ], 
            submoduleCfg: [], 
            userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: 'xxx', url: "https://somerepo.net/scm/someproject/somecomponent.git"]]
        ]
    )
```

Log file from Jenkins shows:

```
[Pipeline] checkout
 > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git config remote.origin.url https://somerepo.net/scm/someproject/somecomponent.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://somerepo.net/scm/someproject/somecomponent.git
 > git --version # timeout=10
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials 
 > git fetch --tags --progress https://somerepo.net/scm/someproject/somecomponent.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
 > git rev-parse release/0.0.1^{commit} # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/release/0.0.1^{commit} # timeout=10
Multiple candidate revisions
Checking out Revision 301c954e576bd3f03ef787563f159d541cb6e8d2 (release/0.0.1)
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f 301c954e576bd3f03ef787563f159d541cb6e8d2
Commit message: "Some old commit message"
 > git rev-list --no-walk 88be7349bd7b6ddb0654325e6b07cf1da2f8a35b # timeout=10
```

In the log file I can see that Jenkins is using the old revision 301c954e576bd3f03ef787563f159d541cb6e8d2 from release/0.0.1 instead of the new remote 88be7349bd7b6ddb0654325e6b07cf1da2f8a35b from refs/remotes/origin/release/0.0.1.

Any ideas whats going wrong here?

Answer (score 5):

I am not a git guru, but try specifying

branches: [[name: "*/release/0.0.1"]],

instead of

branches: [[name: "release/0.0.1"]],

Comment: With that adaption it is working at least, but looks to me like a workaround. No I can see that Jenkins is checking:
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/release/0.0.1^{commit} # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/origin/release/0.0.1^{commit} # timeout=10

The checking of refs/remotes/origin/origin/release/0.0.1 will then run into an error.

Answer (score 1):

I think that this could be related to the use of the `LocalBranch` option to git checkout. If you have previously used this in your workspace:

```
extensions: [
    [$class: 'LocalBranch', localBranch: "release/0.0.1"]
]
```

The Jenkins Git plugin will have checked out that branch locally (rather than just using the revision that referred to at the time). After that it will have a local branch that it can match before checking if that has new changes from upstream. It sounds like the guideline would be to use `LocalBranch` or not but changing between them could cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and "resolved" it by cleaning the workspace directory the hard way, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52959387/3890673). With the next run the problem was gone.

Side note: "Multiple candidate revisions" *might* be related to [this issue](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-37263).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was using a custom workspace and removing the workspace manually but didn't remove the @tmp workspace dir, after removing both directories everything worked fine.

`rm -rf $WORKSPACE*`